# Counter with tags - How to group by dimension/tag?

Tags: java, spring-boot, metrics, micrometer, spring-micrometer

I am trying to understand spring micromenter's group by dimension/tag functionality. I am using StepMeterRegistry and incrementing the counter but don't see desired result.

create counters as,

```
final MeterRegistry myRegistry = new StepMeterRegistry(config, Clock.SYSTEM) {...};

final Counter myCounter1 = myRegistry.counter("myTestCounter", "tag1", "value1");
final Counter myCounter2 = myRegistry.counter("myTestCounter", "tag2", "value2");
final Counter myCounter1n2 = myRegistry.counter("myTestCounter", "tag1", "value1", "tag2", "value2");
```

increment counters as,

```
myCounter1.increment();
myCounter2.increment();
myCounter1n2.increment();
```

when i print (after step duration),

```
myCounter1.measure(); => value=1.0
myCounter2.measure(); => value=1.0
myCounter1n2.measure(); => value=1.0
```

whereas i was expecting (after step duration),

```
myCounter1.measure(); => value=2.0
myCounter2.measure(); => value=2.0
myCounter1n2.measure(); => value=1.0
```

Is my understanding correct ? Or how can i realize group by (or) select by functionality ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find `Counter`s by tags with `MeterRegistry.find()` and aggregate them on your own. AFAICT there's no out-of-box-support for a aggregated value by tags and I'd expect the aggregation happens in a monitoring system.

See [this test](https://github.com/izeye/sample-micrometer-spring-boot/blob/master/src/test/java/learningtest/io/micrometer/core/instrument/step/StepMeterRegistryTests.java) to understand how it works.